# oop php constructor access modifier, which one to use?

Tags: php, constructor, visibility

I've just started experimenting with OO PHP, but there's one basic principle I don't really uderstand that well, and don't find too much info on it.

When creating a `__construct()` method, why would you want it to be `public`, when it's specifically a constructor for that class?
When would you want to call a constructor outside the class?

To me, it seems using a protected constructor is good practice, right?

I know this is basic OO stuff, but I don't find any info directly on it, specifically for constructors.

Answer (score 5):

The `__construct` (not "__constructor") method is the one called when you do `new MyClass()`, i.e. when you instantiate the class. The constructor *needs* to be `public`, unless you only want to instantiate the class from within itself. If the latter, you need at least one other `public static` method you can call in which the class will instantiate itself, otherwise you're unable to create any instance of it.

Comment: Edited the typo. So it's more common to use public constructors?

Comment: @fishbaitfood: Yes, otherwise you cannot really create instances of the class. You'd need other methods to do that for you, as deceze explained in his answer. Didn't you read it? ;) *"The constructor needs to be public [...] otherwise you're unable to create any instance of it."*. Since it is very common to create instances of classes (otherwise, what's the point of OOP when you cannot create objects?), it is common to make the constructor public

Comment: Like I've said, I was over-complicating things. :) I thought you could call all public methods outside the class, even the __construct() one... :)

Comment: @fishbaitfood: Sure, you can, even the `__construct()` one. Nobody stops you from calling it again and again and again.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you create a new instance of a class, the constructor is called. If the constructor is not public, no other code can create an instance of that class.

Hence, if you want to create instances of the class, make the constructor public.

A constructor is always only part the class it is defined in, I don't understand what you mean by *"when it's specifically a constructor for that class"*.

---

**To clarify:**

The only way to invoke the constructor is with `new Class()`. There is no other way to invoke it. `__construct` is a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and there is no way to explicitly call a magic method.

Comment: Because the constructor gets executed automatically after creating a new object. That's what I meant. So I don't really understand when you would call a constructor outside of the class. Maybe I'm over-complicating things..

Comment: You can't. The only way to invoke the constructor is with `new Class()`. There is no way to invoke it any other way. `__construct` is a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and there is no way to explicitly call magic methods.

Comment: You could use a static method to call a private constructor though.